# Add custom clause to HQL join query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hql

I have the Entity `AppVisit` with `ManytoOne` relation with `User` entity. `User` entity has `OneToOne` relation with `UserDetail` Entity.
I need to get all users having number of visits on a specific date less than their `maxDailyVisits`

Below are the classes

```
public class AppVisit{
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private User user;

   private LocalDate visitDate;
}

public class UserDetail{
     private Long id;        
     private int maxDailyVisits;  

     @OneToOne
     private User user;
}
public class User {    

    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<AppVisit> appVisits;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private UserDetail userDetail;  
}
```

Here the HQL query I tried to use in the repository

```
select ud from UserDetail as ud where u.id in 
(select ud1.id from UserDetail as ud1
left join ud1.user.appVisits as av
with acav.visitDate=:visitDate or acav.visitDate is null
Group by u1.id  having Count(ud1.id) < ud1.maxDailyVisits)
```

At the execution time, I got the following SQL query executed to database:

```
select * from "UserDetail" ud
cross join "User" u where ud."User_Id"=u."Id"
and (ud."Id" in
(select ud1."Id" from "UserDetail" ud1
left outer join "User" u1 on ud1."User_Id"=u1."Id"
and (av."VisitDate"=? or av."VisitDate" is null)
left outer join "AppVisit" av
on u1."Id"=av."User_Id"
group by ud1."Id"
having count(ud1."Id")<ud1."MaxDailyVisits"))
```

Also I got this error:

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "av"
```

because the condition on `VisitDate` column was put before the join on `AppVisit` Table

Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the HQL please provide a direct entity class name like below.

```
left join appVisits as av
```

Another issue is you are missing the join condition too. Full query should be like below.

```
select ud from UserDetail as ud where u.id in 
(select ud1.id from UserDetail as ud1
left join appVisits as av on ud1.id = av.user.id
where av.visitDate=:visitDate or av.visitDate is null
Group by u1.id  having Count(ud1.id) < ud1.maxDailyVisits)
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, I got some ideas from your answer to solve my problem. just a note, you meant to make the join with the entity class "AppVisit" and not the property "appVisits". That's how it worked on my side